# Kendo Grid UI bind foreign key column based on other foreign key column value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid

I have a kendo UI grid with two foreign key column Country and Location. while editing, when country column value changed, i want to rebind the Location dropdownlist for edit. Location dropdown should be bound based on the countryid passed.

Really stuck here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use .CascadeFrom("COUNTRY_ID")
in dropdown of the Location
then you need to send the selected country and send to the controller

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. Could you please explain it with example code or sample project.